# How to change name corresponding to pdf link:

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

**How can replace name of downloading pdf file which is just before the link**

**i want it to save as elkinson.pdf not as Elkinson%20Jeffrey.pdf**

CSV File looks like this:

> elkinson https://www.adndrc.org/diymodule/doc_panellist/Elkinson%20Jeffrey.pdf
>
> papers_report http://www.parliament.bm/uploadedFiles/Content/House_Business/Presentation_of_Papers_and_of_Reports/PCA%20Report%209262014.pdf

code:

```
import os
import csv
import requests

write_path = 'C:\\Users\\hgdht\\Desktop\\Downloader_Automation'  # ASSUMING THAT FOLDER EXISTS!

with open('Links.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for link in spamreader:
        if not link:
            continue
        print('-'*72)
        pdf_file = link[0].split('/')[-1]
        with open(os.path.join(write_path, pdf_file), 'wb') as pdf:
            try:
                # Try to request PDF from URL
                print('TRYING {}...'.format(link[0]))
                a = requests.get(link[0], stream=True)
                for block in a.iter_content(512):
                    if not block:
                        break

                    pdf.write(block)
                print('OK.')
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This 
will catch ONLY Requests exceptions
                print('REQUESTS ERROR:')
                print(e)  # This should tell you more details about the error
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the variable pdf_file contains the filename (Presentation_of_Papers_and_of_Reports/PCA%20Report%209262014.pdf), so you can replace that special string by a space using python regex

```
pdf_file =re.sub(r'%[\d]+',' ',pdf_file).lower()
```

ex :

```
import re
pdf_file = "Presentation_of_Papers_and_of_Reports/PCA%20Report%209262014.pdf"
pdf_file =re.sub(r'%[\d]+',' ',pdf_file).lower()
```

output : 'presentation_of_papers_and_of_reports/pca report .pdf'

Comment: See,i have 1000's of pdf's links and before them i have manual names.i want to save that files with that name.@Arun

Comment: split pdf_file using '.' then u can get filename and prefix as pdf, then append whatever prefix you want `pdf_file.split('.')`

Comment: @errata how can i change downloading prefix, which is define before every url.

Comment: i don't want to save by removing symbols. i want to, save by manual names. which is given just before every link.
@Arun